# OnMouseOver Image Issue within Menu

Tags: css

I have been trying to enable the Cog Image to appear correctly whenever a User is Logged-In and MouseOvers the Menu Item which contains the Cog Image.  I would appreciate any help on this.

Here is the Fiddle and you can see the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/V9nBZ/

The small Cog Image will only appear next to the User's Name once he is logged in.

Here is the development site: http://www.virtualpetstore.com

UserId: test4
Password: ninja71

When a User is logged-in and you MouseOver the Button containing the Cog Image, the background-color changes to red, however you are unable to see the Cog Image.
I am not sure how to resolve that.

onMouseOut is able to see the Cog Image:
[image]

onMouseOver is not able to see the Cog Image:
[image]

Whenever a User is logged-in they are within the LoggedInTemplate.  The Anchor Tag that contains the Cog Image, also has the LoginName .Net Control, which displays the UserName:

Here is the code for the Menu:

```
<div id="menu2">
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
  <AnonymousTemplate>
      <ul id="solidmenu" class="solidblockmenu">
         <li><a href="~/default.aspx" runat="server">Incinio</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/empresa.aspx" runat="server">Empresa</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/webgrupodotnet.aspx" runat="server">Deserollo</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/webgrupodiseno.aspx" runat="server">Diseno</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/webgrupomovil.aspx" runat="server">Moviles</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/asociados.aspx" runat="server">Asociados</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/contacto.aspx" runat="server">Contacto</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/Account/Registrar.aspx" id="Registrar" runat="server">Registrar</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" id="HeadLogin" runat="server">Log-In</a></li>
      </ul>
  </AnonymousTemplate>
  <LoggedInTemplate>
      <ul id="solidmenu" class="solidblockmenu">
         <li><a href="~/default.aspx" runat="server">Incinio</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/empresa.aspx" runat="server">Empresa</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/webgrupodotnet.aspx" runat="server">Deserollo</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/webgrupodiseno.aspx" runat="server">Diseno</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/webgrupomovil.aspx" runat="server">Moviles</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/asociados.aspx" runat="server">Asociados</a></li>
         <li><a href="~/contacto.aspx" runat="server">Contacto</a></li>
         <li>
            <span style="width: 25px;">
                <asp:LoginStatus ID="headloginstatus" runat="server"   LogoutAction="redirect" LogoutText="log out" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
            </span>
         </li>
         <li><a href="~/Account/ModifyAccount.aspx"class="modifyuser">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Hola!
                <span style="font-size:13px; padding-left:1px">
                   <asp:LoginName ID="headloginname" runat="server" />
                </span>
             </a>
         </li>          
      </ul>
  </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
</div>
```

Here is the ddmenu.css for this Menu that has the `.solidblockmenu li a:hover`class that changes the background-color to red:

```
.solidblockmenu {
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
float: left;
font: bold 13px Arial;
/*width: 672px;*/
width: 872px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 1em;
border: 1px solid #625e00;
border-width: 1px 0;
background: black url("http://i.imgur.com/iTqzs.gif") center center repeat-x;
}

.solidblockmenu li {
display: inline;
color: #C3C2C2;
}

.solidblockmenu li a{
float: left;
color: #C3C2C2;
padding: 8px 20px 8px  20px;
text-decoration: none;
border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.solidblockmenu li a:visited {
color: #C3C2C2;
}

.solidblockmenu li a:hover, .solidblockmenu li a.selected {   
color: #C3C2C2;
background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/mjYcj.gif") center center repeat-x;
}
```

Here is the registrarse.css which contains the .modifyuser class which has the Cog Image:

```
.modifyuser{
    background: url("/images/home/moduser2.png") no-repeat 4px 8px; 
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I think it is not a problem of the server side, so the ASP-Tags are not helping. Could you post the different HTML output (loogin out/logged in) instead?

Comment: @yunzen the 2 images depict the logged-in and not logged-in scenerios.

Comment: @yunzen I actually resolved the Menu Button text-alignment issue because within the .modifyuser class the height was specified as 19px.  I still have the issue with the cog image not showing up onMouseOver

Comment: Paul is right you have two css images on the same object.  You are effectively replacing the bg image of the cog each time you hover over it with the other bg image.  You should add a <img> or alter a different tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this is the most clean approach because as you can see I have the margin-left: -12px and the background image left margin to -2px

I modified the .modifyuser Class from:

```
.modifyuser {
    background: url("/images/home/moduser2.png") no-repeat 4px 8px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

to use the span like this:

```
a.modifyuser span {       
    background: url("/images/home/moduser2.png") no-repeat scroll -2px -1px transparent;
    margin-left: -12px;     
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    font-size:13px 
}
```

Here is the markup:

```
<li><span>
    <a href="~/Account/ModifyAccount.aspx" class="modifyuser">
        <asp:LoginName ID="headloginname" runat="server" />
    </a>
    </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this rule overriding the style of `.modifyuser`, which has the cog as a background.

```
.solidblockmenu li a:hover, .solidblockmenu li a.selected {         /*Selected Tab style*/
    color: white;
    background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/mjYcj.gif") center center repeat-x;
}
```

You could change it to this, but then you lose the red effect.

```
.solidblockmenu li a:hover:not(.modifyuser), .solidblockmenu li a.selected {         /*Selected Tab style*/
    color: white;
    background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/mjYcj.gif") center center repeat-x;
}
```

Other than that, you would have to add an element to server as the cog.  It could be an img, or a div with absolute positioning, and set the parent to relative positioning.

Comment: Actually the red effect was lost for all of the anchor tags, and that can't work.  You also mentioned that I could have an Div or Img Server tag, which would replace the Cog Image defined in the .modifyuser Class. I'm not sure I follow the part about setting it's parent to relative positioning. What is the parent?